# Audio continues after removing <video> element in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I am having issues with video support in Chrome. My web page must run in Chrome and I am using the following code to check periodically if the web page has to play a video or not... but the problem is that after I remove the  element, I still hear the audio and when I recreate the  eleemnt, the audio of the new video and the old overlaps.

```
function showVideo() {
        var video = videodata;

        var videobox = $('#videobox').first();
        var videoplayer = $('#videoplayer').first();

        if (video.Enabled) {
            if ((videoplayer.length > 0 && videoplayer[0].currentSrc != video.Location) || videoplayer.length == 0) {
                videobox.empty();
                videobox.append('<video id="videoplayer" preload="auto" src="' + video.Location + '" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" />');
                videobox.show();
            }
        } else {
            videobox.hide();
            videobox.empty(); // Clear any children.
        }
    }
```

How can I solve?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

The following was the minimum I had to go to get this to work.  I was actually experiencing a stall due to the buffering while spawning ajax requests when the user pressed the back button.  Pausing the video in Chrome and the Android browser kept it buffering.  The non-async ajax request would get stuck waiting for the buffering to finish, which it never would.

Binding this to the beforepagehide event fixed it.

```
 $("#SOME_JQM_PAGE").live("pagebeforehide", function(event)
 {
           $("video").each(function () 
           { 
               logger.debug("PAUSE VIDEO");
               this.pause();
               this.src = "";
           });
 });
```

This will clear every video tag on the page.

Answer (score 1):

firsly try to create "video" tag empty in the html and create "source" tag into javascript code

```
<html>
.
.
<video id="main-video" autoplay=""></video>
.
.
</html>


<script>
   $('#main-video').append('<source type="video/mp4" src="URL.mp4">');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to pause the video first before removing it otherwise the audio is still playing in the background. The reason I used pause is because there is no stop() function on html5 video element.

```
        } else {
        videobox.hide();

        // you can add something like this
        $("#videoplayer").pause();

        videobox.empty(); // Clear any children.
    }
```

Comment: jQuery cannot play with <video> element. try: document.getElementById("videoplayer").pause();

Comment: To access the DOM element directly with jQuery you should do `$('#videoplayer')[0].pause()`.

Answer (score 0):

try (based on SimpleCode's answer):

`function showVideo() {
        var video = videodata;`

```
    var videobox = $('#videobox').first();
    var videoplayer = $('#videoplayer').first();

    if (video.Enabled) {
        if ((videoplayer.length > 0 && videoplayer[0].currentSrc != video.Location) || videoplayer.length == 0) {
            videobox.empty();
            videobox.append('<video id="videoplayer" preload="auto" src="' + video.Location + '" width="100%" height="100%" loop="loop" />');
            videobox.show();
            document.getElementById("videoplayer").play();
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("videoplayer").pause();
        videobox.hide();
        videobox.empty(); // Clear any children.
    }
}
```